# Combining NSStringCompareOptions values

Tags: swift

I would like to do a case insensitive search for a string within another, starting from the rear end of the source string. I've tried the following:

let r = s.rangeOfString( substr.toString(), options: (NSStringCompareOptions.BackwardsSearch | NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch) )

But Swift complains that I can't use the "|" operator to combine the options (also tried '+'). What's the syntax here? Thanks

Comment: This is certainly a duplicate.  This now uses set style notation `[NSStringCompareOptions.BackwardsSearch, NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch]`.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR, you found the duplicate before I did!